# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint | ASP.NET Core & Entity Framework Core Code First

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table named **Company**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Companies](
    [Id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [ActiveStatus] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Phone1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Phone2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CompanyId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [IsParent] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Companies] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Companies_Companies_CompanyId] FOREIGN KEY([CompanyId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Companies] ([Id])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Companies] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Companies_Companies_CompanyId]
GO
```

I made this using `ASP.NET Core` code first, this is my class

```
public class BaseClass
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string ActiveStatus { get; set; }
    }

public class Company: BaseClass
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Address { get; set; }

        public string Phone1 { get; set; }

        public string Phone2 { get; set; }

        public string Email { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Company")]
        public Guid CompanyId { get; set; }
        public Company ParentCompany { get; set; }

        public string IsParent { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Company> ParentCompanies { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }
        public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to insert data to my table using a query

```
INSERT [dbo].[Companies] ([Id], [ActiveStatus], [Name], [Address], [Phone1], [Phone2], [Email], [CompanyId], [IsParent]) VALUES (N'af85a23c-3832-47c9-3efe-08d79f1b5659', N'Active', N'PT. Sari Coffee Indonesia', N'Sahid Sudirman Center 27th Floor, Jl. Jend. Sudirman No.Kav. 86, RT.10/RW.11, Karet Tengsin, Kota Jakarta Pusat, Daerah Khusus Ibukota Jakarta 10220', N'+62 21 574 6501', N'+62 21 574 5808', N'feedback@starbucks.co.id', N'00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', N'1')
GO
```

But I got an error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 3 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the FOREIGN KEY SAME TABLE constraint
>   "FK_Companies_Companies_CompanyId". The conflict occurred in database
>   "CRMandOMS", table `"dbo.Companies"`, column `'Id'`. The statement has
>   been terminated.

Please help

Comment: Seems like there is no row with id = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' in the table, so the FK isn't fulfilled.

Comment: @jarlh So what should I do?

Comment: The FK is there to make sure only valid/known CompanyId's are stored. (I.e. existing Id's.) Why are you trying to store an unknown CompanyId?

Comment: @jarlh I'm not, I actually was messing around with my code, I added some ICollection, and migrate, and update database, because last time it wasn't self referencing. So either I give a null or 000 guid

Comment: Perhaps you should store null here?

Comment: @jarlh I did, can't store null

Comment: Seems like your table has some design issues...

Comment: You can either allow CompanyID to be NULL or set CompanyID to be equal to ID.  i.e. use 'af85a23c-3832-47c9-3efe-08d79f1b5659' for both ID and CompanyID.  This would mean that the company you are trying to insert has no parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wanna add `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` as a `CompanyId`, so you faced with this error occurs because in your table there is no company with this `Id`.

In your scenario there is a possibility of having a company with **no** parent, so your table design is wrong. for resolving this error you have to make the `CompanyId` foreign key `nullable`.

do like below:

```
...

[ForeignKey("Company")]
public Guid? CompanyId { get; set; }

...
```

Then `Add-Migration` and `Update-Database` for changing the database. Now, you can insert a company with `Null` parent.

good luck